# How to fix Infinite load screen bug for Swtor (Steam)

Tags: graphics

I downloaded swtor off steam. And I am able to launcher the launcher, sign in, hit play. But when the loading page comes up. It stays on the loading image. The tiny wheel is spinning, but nothing ever loads. Any advice on how to fix?

Comment: Hello. I see you are having an issue with a game running on Steam. This has nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS. This would be a good question to ask Steam Support.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked [protondb](https://www.protondb.com/app/1286830), and I am assuming you are referring to STAR WARS: The Old Republic.

First, would you be able to tell me what version of Proton you are running the game under? You can find that by clicking Steam (Top Left) > Setting (I think) > Steam Play > Force Games to run using Proton > Proton Version.

> I am doing this off memory, while sick, so this may be wrong.

People on ProtonDB are stating that Experimental and 7.0.1 work flawlessly. Personally I always use Glorious Eggroll, but that is a personal preference.